# What is the safest way to change MongoDB server structure?

Tags: amazon-ec2, replication, mongodb, sharding

I currently have a MongoDB replica set configured as such:

```
{
    "_id" : "ahspy_mongo_set",
    "version" : 13,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "remotedatacenter.in.montreal.dns.com",
                    "priority" : 0
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "t1.micro.at.ec2.dns.com",
                    "arbiterOnly" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "m1.xlarge.at.ec2.dns.com"
            }
    ]
}
```

So basically, one server at EC2 that backups up to another server in Montreal which, for multiple reasons, cannot become master.

I want to change my structure and I'm not sure where to start without causing a lot of trouble. In fact, I'm not even sure what I want to do is possible.

What I want to do is take the main DB server I have at EC2 (m1.xlarge) and turn it into 3 m1.large shards. So basically, go from:

- Replica at EC2 (m1.xlarge)
- Backup Replica in Montreal
- Arbiter

to

- Replica at EC2

  - Shard 1 (m1.large)
  - Shard 2 (m1.large)
  - Shard 3 (m1.large)
- Backup Replica in Montreal
- Arbiter

Is this possible? Can I shard the replica set in EC2 while keeping only one server in the replica in Montreal? If so, what's the proper way to do this? I'm having a real "Chicken and Egg" issue with Replication/Sharding in Mongo so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic steps:

1. Start up mongos and config servers
2. Make this replica set your first shard.
3. Add shard 2
4. Add shard 3

You can't use your backup replica as backup for all of your shards: it's just backup for that one replica set.

You should set up a separate replica set for each shard.  If there's capacity for it on the Montreal server, you could put a backup member for shards 2 and 3 on that server, but they'd have to be separate *mongod* processes from the shard 1 member.

Comment: i'd take this advice since she works for 10gen

Comment: Kristina: "You should set up a separate replica set for each shard." I've looked at the mongo sharding documentation 10ths of times and that's the part I'm not sure I understand correctly. What are you supposed to do first? Shard or Replicate? I'm having a hard time understanding the concept :\.

Comment: I did a blog post on this that might be helpful, it goes through setting them up together in more detail: http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/08/30/return-of-the-mongo-mailbag/

Comment: That was **exactly** the kind of documentation that my stupid brain needed. In fact, it looks like it was written for me :D. Thank you sooo much.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)